# JQuery Elements not visible on webpage

Tags: jquery, json, jsp, servlets

I have been making an application in which i am using jQuery widgets for the UI. Everything was working fine until it just got stuck and there was no data visible on the webpage(only the text was visible, but all jQuery elements went missing. I am not able to figure out what is the problem as I have included all the necessary JAR files and JAVASCRIPT files. I am putting my code snippet here. Any help will be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.`enter code here`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray" %>

    <% JSONArray jasonList = (JSONArray)(request.getAttribute("listjson"));
       String chartformat = (String)(request.getAttribute("chartformat") == null ? "Default , 100" : request.getAttribute("chartformat")) ;
       System.out.println("chartformat in jsp = "+chartformat);
    %>

<head>
    <title id='Description'>This example shows how to create a Grid from JSON data.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/configuratorUReport.css" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/globalize.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxdata.export.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxgrid.export.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="generatedata.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqxchart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var jsondata ='<%=jasonList%>'; 
            var source =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [
                    { name: 'region', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'sumComplete', type: 'int' },
                    { name: 'sumInComplete', type: 'int' },
                    { name: 'sumVoided', type: 'int' },
                    { name: 'sumTotalConfigs', type: 'int' },
                    { name: 'sumUsers', type: 'int' }
                ],
                id: 'id',
                localdata : jsondata
            };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: 670,
                source: dataAdapter,
                columnsresize: true,
                columns: [
                  { text: 'REGION', datafield: 'region', width: 180 },
                  { text: 'COMPLETED', datafield: 'sumComplete', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'INCOMPLETED', datafield: 'sumInComplete', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'VOIDED', datafield: 'sumVoided', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'TOTAL CONFIGURATIONS', datafield: 'sumTotalConfigs', minwidth: 180 },
                  { text: 'FUJITSU INTERNAL USERS', datafield: 'sumUsers', minwidth: 180 }
              ]
            });
            $("#excelExport").jqxButton({ theme: theme });

            $("#excelExport").click(function () {
                $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'xls', 'jqxGrid');           
            });

            //CODE FOR drawing Chart

            var chartdata ='<%=chartformat%>';
            //var chartdata =  "APAC-CHINA, 40 \n APAC, 60";
             var source1 =
             {
                 datatype: "csv",
                 datafields: [
                     { name: 'Region' },
                     { name: 'Share' }
                 ],
                  localdata : chartdata    
                // url: chartdata
             };
               // var dataAdapter1 = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source1, { async: false, autoBind: true, loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert('Error loading "' + source.localdata + '" : ' + error); } });
                //var dataAdapter1 = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source1);
                var dataAdapter1 = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source1, { async: false, autoBind: true, loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert('Error loading "' + source.localdata + '" : ' + error); } });
             // prepare jqxChart settings
               var settings = {
                         title: "Configurator Usage: Total Configurations per Region",
                         description: "",
                         enableAnimations: true,
                         showLegend: false,
                         legendPosition: { left: 520, top: 140, width: 100, height: 100 },
                         padding: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 },
                         titlePadding: { left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
                         source: dataAdapter1,
                         colorScheme: 'scheme02',
                         seriesGroups:
                             [
                                 {
                                     type: 'pie',
                                     showLabels: true,
                                     series:
                                         [
                                             { 
                                                 dataField: 'Share',
                                                 displayText: 'Region',
                                                 labelRadius: 100,
                                                 initialAngle: 15,
                                                 radius: 130,
                                                 centerOffset: 0,
                                                 formatSettings: { sufix: '%', decimalPlaces: 1 }
                                             }
                                         ]
                                 }
                             ]
                     };

                     // setup the chart
                     $('#jqxChart').jqxChart(settings);


        });
    </script>

</head>
<body class='default'>
<form name = "CURform" id="CURform" method = "post" action="ConfiguratorStatusReport">
<div align="center"><h3>Configurator Usage Report</h3>
<div id='content'>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var item = "";
            $(document).ready(function () {                
                var source = [
                    "PRIMEQUEST",
                    "ETERNUS",
                    "PRIMERGY"
                ];

                // Create a jqxDropDownList
                $("#jqxdropdownlist").jqxDropDownList({ source: source, selectedIndex: 0, width: '200', height: '25'});
                // bind to 'select' event.
                $('#jqxdropdownlist').bind('select', function (event) {
                    var args = event.args;
                    item = $('#jqxdropdownlist').jqxDropDownList('getItem', args.index);
                    //alert('Selected: ' + item.label);
                });
            });


        </script>

        <div id='jqxWidget'>
        </div>
        <div id='jqxdropdownlist'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <table>
   <tr>
            <!-- <td id=8ptN align=left> Start Date&nbsp;</td><td id=8ptN><input type=text class="inpt" value="" name="fromdate" title="Enter Date in MM/DD/YYYY format" size=20>&nbsp;
<img src="calendar.jpg" border="0" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>


            <td id=8ptN align=right> End Date&nbsp;</td><td id=8ptN><input type=text class="inpt" value="" name="todate" title="Enter Date in MM/DD/YYYY format" size=20>&nbsp;
<img src="calendar.jpg" border="0" alt=""></td> -->
<td id=8ptN align=left> Start Date&nbsp;<div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {               
                // Create a jqxDateTimeInput
                $("#startdate").jqxDateTimeInput({width: '250px', height: '25px'});
                $("#enddate").jqxDateTimeInput({width: '250px', height: '25px'});

            });
        </script>
        <div id='startdate'>
        </div>
        </div>
</td>
<td id=8ptN align=left> End Date&nbsp;<div>
        <script type="text/javascript">


         function submitform(){
            var item2 = $('#enddate').jqxDateTimeInput('getText');
            var item1 = $('#startdate').jqxDateTimeInput('getText');
                $('#prdType').val(item.label);
                $('#SDType').val(item1);
                $('#EDType').val(item2);
                // alert('submitform--Selected: ' + $('#EDType').val());
                $('#CURform').submit();

            }
        </script>
        <div id='enddate'>
        </div>
        </div>
</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type = "hidden" id = "prdType" name = "prdType"/>
        <input type = "hidden" id = "SDType" name = "SDType"/>
        <input type = "hidden" id = "EDType" name = "EDType"/></td>
        <td align=center><input id = 'jqxButton' type="button" onclick ="submitform()" value = "Go">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="button" value = "Reset"></td>
        </tr>
   </table>
   <table>
   <tr>
   <td>
   <div id='jqxWidget' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: left;">
        <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
        <div style='margin-top: 20px;'>
            <div style='float: left;'>
                <input type="button" value="Export to Excel" id='excelExport' />
                <br /><br />
               <!--   <input type="button" value="Export to XML" id='xmlExport' />-->
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td> <div id='host' style="margin: 0 auto; width: 699px; height: 400px;">
        <div id='jqxChart' style="width: 680px; height: 400px; position: relative; left: 0px;
            top: 0px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using `Firefox` or `Google Chrome`, you can start the `console` and see if you have som errors. In `Chrome` you push the `F12` button or `Ctrl+Shift+J` (Cmd instead of Ctrl if you're on iOS).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric. It got resolved. I was actually using IE-8 and it was the problem of document mode. As i ran the code on Chrome, it worked fine. Thank you :) :)